# Neo4j database research

Tags: java, database, neo4j

I recently started researching database features of databases. 
At the moment I'm looking into Neo4j Graph database.

Unfortunately, I can't find every bit of information I need.
I found most information except the following:

- Supporting datatypes? (Integer,
- Max. database size?
- Max. nodes in db?
- Max. relations in db?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The supported datatypes:

- boolean or boolean[]
- byte or byte[]
- short or short[]
- int or int[]
- long or long[]
- float or float[]
- double or double[]
- char or char[]
- java.lang.String or String[]

Source: [Neo4j API docs](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

There's no limit on database size, but the current release (1.2) has limitations on the number of nodes, relationships and properties. The limit on each of these is 4 billion. The work on increasing the limits is done right now, and will be included in a milestone release soon. The new limit is 32B on nodes and relationships and 64B on properties.

In the 1.3.M03 milestone release support for a more efficient way of storing short strings was included, which will lower disk consumption considerably for many datasets. See [Better support for short strings in Neo4j](http://journal.thobe.org/2011/02/better-support-for-short-strings-in.html).

Comment: thx for your amazingly fast answer! Really helpful. If anybody want's to know the source of the 'increasing the limits..' part, there's a blog post about it: http://blog.neo4j.org/2011_01_01_archive.html